# Spring Boot uses more memory to run in Linux than Windows

Tags: java, windows, spring, spring-boot, linux-kernel

I am trying to figure out why a same web application uses more memory in **Ubuntu Linux 16** than running in **Windows 10**. Is there any reason for it? I always thought Linux was faster and lighter to run any application in server mode. By the way, both operating system (OS) are 64 bit.

*See below screenshots and memory consumed.*

**Windows 10**[image: Windows 10]
**Ubuntu Linux**
[image: Ubuntu Linux]
As you can see in task managers, Linux is using more morey to run the same application. I also tried to run Spring Boot in a VM 64 bit and this requires more memory than running in a simple VM 32 bit.

Is Windows better to manage Java application with Spring Boot?

Comment: 1) The task manager is not a good way to assess memory usage. 2) The Java JVM is designed to use as much memory as you allow it - you haven't told us what settings you are using. 3) Why do you care?

Comment: You´re right, in above samples I did not provide any java option. So, in my tests I set -Xmx128 -Xms128m for both OS, and even this way Linux uses more memory to run. For Example Linux RSS 126M and Windows 102M. I also tried -client option for VM in Linux and anything has changed.

Comment: Windows and Linux have different memory management techniques.

Comment: I agree about it, but task managers should inform how much memory is used, isn't it?

Comment: Memory usage isn't a single figure. There's the working set, commit charge, or reserved memory. Whenever you look at a number, it is subject to interpretation. And really, why do you care? Unless profiling indicates that there is an issue, don't try to fix it.

Comment: I am just trying to figure out those numbers in task manager and how i can save memory in Linux

Comment: Have you verified (using a profiler, for example), that you need to save memory? If you haven't, then don't fix it. There is no problem to fix.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, Windows and Linux have different memory management systems. There are a variety of reasons their memory usage could be different, for instance, if Windows Java is using a dynamic link library (DLL) loaded by another application, it may not be including the shared library in the memory allocation calculation. In addition, the code required to implement JVM and it's API on Windows versus Linux could be different.

Windows and Linux may be paging or swapping different parts of the JVM to disk while the program is running based on the operating systems configuration and how the kernel is programmed.

Your best bet is to run the code through a Java Profiler like VisualVM to try to get more information on how much memory various parts of the application is using. Windows can be notoriously tricky to calculate the actual memory usage of a program, see https://superuser.com/questions/895168/how-to-measure-total-ram-usage-of-a-program-under-windows

Comment: When we start moving all applications from a single application server to many Spring Boot applications, memory management is a tricky question. For example a big heap of 4gb can not be the same as 4 Spring Boot apps of 1gb running in the end. There many implicit memory consumers to run this same application. That's why I'm trying to figure out the better way to run the application even in Windows or Linux.